# Command that exits with zero status (not /bin/true)?

Tags: command-line

I've got a Makefile that runs a tool that takes a little while; it allows me to replace the command used:

```
make TOOL=alternative-tool
```

I'd like to skip that step in the Makefile, so I'm looking for a command that exits with status 0, and that has negligible side-effects.

Obviously, I could just use `true`, but that's kinda confusing:

```
make TOOL=true
```

That reads as if I *want* to run the tool, but I don't.

Is there a default-installed executable that isn't `/bin/true` that exits with status 0, and that has a catchy and easy to type name?

Comment: Makefiles support comments, https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Contents.html . Put a comment before the line and document your code. That reduces confusion and explains why you used a certain approach.

Comment: What line? The `TOOL=true` will be on the command line when invoking make, probably documented in a README nearby. The actual line that invokes the tool is somewhere within a 7000-line (third party) makefile.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Even though you've asked for something that is "not `/bin/true`", replacing `true` with the full name `/bin/true` to show that it is the `true` program rather than some other meaning of "true" is probably the best solution.

Your concern is that the `true` in

```
make TOOL=true
```

appears to be something other than a command name. But if you write

```
make TOOL=/bin/true
```

then that is unambiguously a command. Somebody might misread `TOOL=true` to mean that some other tool somewhere is intended, but no such misreading of `TOOL=/bin/true` is likely.

---

I am unsure as to when `:`, which is a shell builtin but not an external command, will work. [Henning Makholm](https://askubuntu.com/users/410876/henning-makholm) has [reported that it appears to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026369/command-that-exits-with-zero-status-not-bin-true/1026371?noredirect=1#comment1668016_1026371). But I think it does not work in all situations, and [you found that it did not work for you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026369/command-that-exits-with-zero-status-not-bin-true/1026371?noredirect=1#comment1668056_1026371).

As for a shell alias, you cannot use that because alias expansion is not performed in the arguments you pass to a command, nor do makefiles make any use of previously defined shell aliases. Even if `make` runs your commands in a new shell, that shell will not have the alias (and would not use it even if it did have it, because it would be a noninteractive shell, where alias expansion is not automatically enabled).

Comment: Using `:` seems to work fine for me. `make` always spawns a shell to run each command after it's done its own substitutions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks, I've edited. You may want to post an answer. [Lok Lam Cheng](https://askubuntu.com/users/541997/lok-lam-cheng) had [commented on the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026369/command-that-exits-with-zero-status-not-bin-true/1026371?noredirect=1#comment1667980_1026369) to suggest `:`, but it should be an answer (especially if correct) and that comment doesn't explain why one should expect it to work. In a directory with `hello.c` and no makefile, where `make hello` compiles `hello.c` to `hello`, I found `make CC=: hello` behaved according to what you are saying.

Comment: Unfortunately, for this particular Makefile (it uses _erlang.mk_), using `:` doesn't work. Being explicit about `/bin/true` is probably the best way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that using the full path to `true` would be the best solution, I'd like to note what's probably by far the most common way to avoid real command execution: sticking an `echo` in front of it. So:

```
make TOOL=echo
```

Comment: I think this is sometimes useful when it's important one be reminded that one suppressed whatever action `TOOL` would otherwise do. Without `-s` or equivalent, `make` emits redundant information, because both `make` and the `echo` command run by `make` separately emit output. For example, when I run `make CC=echo hello` in a directory that has `hello.c` and no makefile, I get `echo     hello.c   -o hello` as the first line of output and `hello.c -o hello` as the second. But some builds use (or the user may add) `-s`, and then it's helpful. `make -s CC=echo hello` gives just `hello.c -o hello`.

Comment: (which might still be useful if the commands involve shell expansions, so you can get a clearer idea of what's being run, if interested)

Answer (score 5):

You can always make your own command that does nothing but return a zero exit status. Some options:

- an appropriately named symbolic link to `/bin/true`
- an empty shell script
- a nearly empty C program:

  ```c
  int main() {
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: A good name for such a program would be noop or no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link in the working directory to /bin/true named something like `skip`. Thus...

```
skip -> /bin/true
```

Then the make line can be ...

```
make TOOL=./skip
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to do it with slightly more characters:

```
function T() { /bin/true; }
```

After you've done it once you can re-execute it just by using the name `T`.

```
false; T; echo $?
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this function can be invoked from a Make variable value (to be of use in the situation in question)?